# About regularization of max function

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis, regularization

I have a question in Demailly's book(Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry in Page 43):

> Let $\theta \in C^{\infty}(R)$ be a nonnegative function with support in [-1,1] such that
> $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\theta(h)dh=1$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}h\theta(h)dh=0$ .
> For arbitrary $\eta=(\eta_1,\eta_2,...,\eta_p)\in \mathbb{R_+}^p $,the function
> \begin{equation} M_{\eta}(t_1,t_2,...t_p)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}max\{t_1+h_1,t_2+h_2,...t_p+h_p\}\prod_{1\leq i \leq p}\theta(h_i/\eta_i)/\eta_idh_1...dh_p
> \end{equation} is non decreasing in all variables, smooth and convex on $\mathbb{R}^p$.

I know that the function is non decreasing and smooth. However,I'm failed in proving the convexity of this function.I have tried to calculate the Hessian Matrix of it, but I'm not sure that the Hessian Matrix is semi-positive definite.

Comment: If you have a parameterized family of convex functions, then the expectation with respect to the parameters is convex. That is, If $f(x,y)$ is convex in $x$ then $E_y f$ is too.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean that the max function is a convex function?

Comment: Yes, max is a convex function. In general, maximum of convex functions is convex (and linear functions are convex). See [operations that preserve convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Operations_that_preserve_convexity)

Comment: I know. We can use the  definition of convexity. Thank you!